If I put up money for someone else to take out a secured loan, is that also considered a loan?
There is a similar question, Can a friend put up collateral for my secured loan?, but since I can't add a comment and my question is slightly different, I decided to create a new question:
If I provide funds to a friend for them to use as collateral for a secured loan in the same amount, are those funds also considered a loan if I expect them to be repaid?  In other words, will I be responsible for tax on the corresponding forgone interest?

Your question seems identical to the one asked, except the other person is a friend, instead of your mother. What am I missing?

Tax on corresponding forgone interest depends on jurisdiction. You didn't mention where you are. If you give someone something with the mutual expectation of it being returned - it's a loan, by definition.

@Grade'Eh'Bacon: The difference is that I'm asking whether the funds I supply create a second loan between me and friend in addition to the secured loan, which is a contract between my friend and my friend's bank.  If the funds I supply are also considered a loan, then I would be liable for tax on the interest I should have imposed per IRS.  The linked question only asks about the possibility of supplying such funds.

@littleadv: I was just wondering from the point of view of the IRS.

If you're talking about the US tax law then see the last two points in the duplicate answer.

@littleadv: Only the third point of the (non)duplicate question seems relevant, and from my understanding is wrong—there is no gift tax in the case of a bona-fide loan; the lender is responsible for taxes on the interest income implied by the AFR.

That's exactly what it says

@littleadv: It's not: " For bona fide loans, there is no fixed upper limit on the amount you can loan, but the gift tax will be determined based on the difference between the interest charged and the "applicable federal rate" (this rule is found in IRC Sec. 7872; check IRS.gov for monthly Rev. Proc.'s listing newest AFR's)." There is no gift tax in this context, contrary to the quoted comment.

Yes, there is. If you charge less interest than AFR - that's a gift.

@littleadv: It's not treated as a gift by the IRS—it doesn't trigger a gift tax for the lender; it triggers tax on the implied interest income.

Yes, it also triggers gift tax on the implied gift. If you don't charge someone $1M in interest - they got a gift of $1M. Gifts are in fact double taxed, it's always after tax money that's being taxed for gift tax.

@littleadv: Sorry, I was thinking in terms of the scale of loan as in the example ($20K), where the forgone interest is less than the annual exclusion.  The issue I have with the third point of the chosen answer to the linked question is that it doesn't mention the tax on the implied interest income, and in addition, the answer as a whole doesn't address the primary consequence: If supplying funds to a friend to serve as collateral for a secured load itself constitutes a loan, then what reason is there to have a secured loan at all instead of just having me loan my friend the funds directly.

It does talk about the implied interest, that's what it talks about. The fact that the interest is below exemption is only relevant because you realize that gift tax applies. As to the last point - that's between you and your friend.

@littleadv: You're seeing things are that invisible to me:  Where is it mentioned that the lender is responsible for the implied interest income?

Hmmm... It mentioned the IRC Sec. 7872 explicitly, that's all that section is talking about.

@littleadv: So you agree it's not in the answer, which isn't very helpful for folks who come here for help.

It is there, explicitly, what do you want me to agree on?

@littleadv: Being referred to the tax code is bit like my grandfather telling me to read the encyclopedia when I asked him a question — it's not an answer.  But after pulling so many teeth, I think I can write my own answer now, so thank you for thar.

No worries, you're welcome.
